# RTLCSS And Element Plus With Vue Js Project

Tags: css, vue.js, vite, element-plus, rtlcss

As element plus doesn't support RTL I had to use other third party libraries like `rtlcss` plugin and actually this is solved the problem, but not in my application case where i use both rtl and ltr directions so the `rtlcss` plugin is always converts the styles into rtl regardless of the html dir value, any solution for this issue?

here's my vite.config.js file:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url';
import rtlcss from 'rtlcss';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import AutoImport from 'unplugin-auto-import/vite';
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite';
import { ElementPlusResolver } from 'unplugin-vue-components/resolvers';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import tailwindcss from 'tailwindcss';


export default defineConfig({
  css: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [
        rtlcss,
        tailwindcss,
      ],
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    AutoImport({
      resolvers: [ElementPlusResolver()],
    }),
    Components({
      resolvers: [ElementPlusResolver()],
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
});
```